# What is the hold up on account deletion?

Tags: support, accounts, deletion

I have deleted all my SO accounts and all have gone through in around 24 hours, except the one for Stack Overflow.

This one has been "scheduled" since Nov 5, well over a week ago.
[image]

I signed out of everything and left it alone for several working days.  Still nothing.

So what's the issue?  Actually, I suppose I don't care at this point.  Please just sort your stuff out and delete my account, like you promised that you would.

I am not going to click cancel, so don't wait on me.

This isn't a duplicate question because the others don't get an answer that's valid here.  It says that it'll take up to 24 hours to be deleted.  This has now taken over 240 hours and running.  Why is that eh?

Comment: From my (limited) understanding of the process, a little bit of manual review/effort may be required for accounts over a reputation threshold. This is probably what's causing the delay.

Comment: bah, if they un-mod someone before they even did anything wrong then they can be speedy enough if the motivation takes them.  Oh well GDPR is my friend.

Comment: It’s still a duplicate, irrespective of the passage of time, since the answer is the exact same. Deletion of accounts with a significant amount of reputation has to manually reviewed/approved by a staff member. I imagine that they’re backed up right now, with all the new policies and a likely increase in the number of users requesting account deletion. Is there some urgency to completing this process? You could contact the team via email, using the “contact” page linked in the site footer.